# Can't add fragments, XML, activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-fragments

My `Android Studio` now when opening a project, it does not directly go to the App folder. Also, I can't run my project anymore. I can't add more `XML` files, `Fragments`, `Activities` etc. I can only New -> Source file, `html` file etc.

When I try to create a new project, it has different types of create (like `Java`, `Gradle`, `Groovy`, etc) to choose. Not like basic to create `Activity` only. What should I do? Please help me. (In this newly create project I can not even find where to create `Activity`).

Sorry guys, I forgot to mention I used `Android Studio` in Ubuntu.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Lazy solution: Uninstall and reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot related to this scenario?

Comment: I aready uninstall an reinstall it
I posted image. Please help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what IntelliJ looks like which Android Studio is derived from. Probably the problem is the Android Plugins is **deactivated**. You can activate it from `File -> Setting -> Plugins` like the following picture:

[image]

If the problem still persists, you can try removing `.AndroidStudio3.0` (based on your Android Studio version) from your home directory. In Linux, you can get the home directory by using the following command:

```
echo $HOME
```

Then you can find the directory by showing all the hidden files from your  File Manager after opening your home directory. In my system, the Android Studio folder resides in:

```
/home/user/.AndroidStudio3.0
```

That probably different in your system. Unfortunately, I don't use Ubuntu but Slackware. So, I can't make sure where the Android Studio folder is.

Comment: Thanks. It really help. It's about plug in. Again. Thank you so much

Comment: @TuấnMạnhNguyễn: It my answer solve your problem, please accept it as an accepted answer to close the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

i have face same problem then i get solution from setup sdk path .
if you have no sdk folder in root/android directory then download and then try to build your project.

open SdkManager --> Android sdk location--> edit

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hello, I hope this will help you ,I think you have accidentally selected the wrong menu so just look at the screen shot that i have attached,in that you can see at up left corner there's a project window you have to click on that and after the you can see your project and above your project there is another drop down menu,so in that menu you have to select android and after that you can add xml,java and other files to you project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mash up! Simple, but I only know for windows

Go to this location in your pc

```
C:\Users\[Username]
```

In this location you have noticed a direcctory call `.AndroidStudio`

**Delete** it.

Now your android studio is totally reset.

To Get the Preview

You have to set the path of your sdk.

right click on the **project folder (app) --> Open Module Settings --> SDK Location on sidebar --> setup your sdk folder**

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks a lot but im using it on ubuntu. Do you know how to fix

Comment: In ubuntu delete .AndriodStudio in your home folder. mind .AndroidStudio is hidden folder.